# Manual typing format of date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I am using [ng-pick-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) for selecting and displaying dates. I have changed to format of the date to `DD/MM/YYYY` using `dateTimeAdapter.setLocale('en-IN')` in constructor. If I click the calendar and select the date Its in format of `DD/MM/YYYY` but If I manually type `03/28/2019`, it still accepts. I want to restrict other format except `DD/MM/YYYY` even on typing. Please help me out.

**Code**

```
<input (ngModelChange)="onChangeDate($event)" [(ngModel)]="dob" name="date" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" [owlDateTime]="dt1" required>
<owl-date-time class="" [pickerType]="'calendar'" [startView]="'multi-years'" #dt1></owl-date-time>

import { DateTimeAdapter } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
constructor(dateTimeAdapter: DateTimeAdapter<any>){dateTimeAdapter.setLocale('en-IN');}
```

Comment: You can do a validation in `onChangeDate` event

Comment: And please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48702408/angular-5-ng-pick-datetime-date-format

Comment: for typing ? @RameshRajendran

Comment: Still I Could manually enter @RameshRajendran

Comment: Why you are allowing to type in that text box? Is it really needed to the user?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to validate your input. Here I have provided solution to your problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-pick-datetime-format-i18n-qwhyb3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

I have added type of input as "text", pattern as you needed "DD/MM/YYYY" and background css to get valid and invalid status of input tag.

```
<input type="text" pattern="^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$" (ngModelChange)="onChangeDate($event)" [(ngModel)]="dob" name="date" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" [owlDateTime]="dt1" required>
```